How can i perform apple pay with flutter stripe #Update: Fixed
following section gives payment button for apple pay
if (_selectedMethodIndex == 4)
                        BottomAppBar(
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 20.0),
                                child: PlatformPayButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    print('apple pay loading');
                                    _handleApplePayPress(context);
                                  },
                                  // onPressed: () =>
                                  //     _handleApplePayPress(context),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

then further for handling the press event following section is written down:
void _handleApplePayPress(BuildContext context) async{
print('pay pressed');
try {
  if (await Stripe.instance.isPlatformPaySupported()) {
    print('apple pay is supported');
    bool paymentSuccessful = await _payWithApplePay() ?? false;
    if (paymentSuccessful) {
      // If payment is successful then execute this code
      print('payment successful');
    } else {
      // if payment failed
      print('payment failed');
    }
  } else {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Apple pay is not supported in this device'),
    ));
  }
} catch (exception) {
  print(exception.toString());
}

}
Future<bool?> _payWithApplePay() async{
    print("controller methods");
    
  }

i did this
i got the Apple pay button
now i need to do further processing which i don't know how to do..
I perform following and it fixed:
     void _handleApplePayPress(
    BuildContext context,
    List<CartItem>? cartItem,
    String orderType,
    double orderTotalPrice,
  ) async {
    print('pay pressed');
    try {
      print('trying');
      final SecretResponse response =
          await CustomerOrderRepository().submitOrder(
        cartItem: cartItem!,
        orderType: orderType,
        totalAmount: orderTotalPrice,
        publicVouchers: publicVouchers ?? [],
        privateVouchers: privateVouchers ?? [],
      );
      if (response.clientSecret != null) {
        try {
          final paymentIntentResult =
              await Stripe.instance.confirmPlatformPayPaymentIntent(
            clientSecret: response.clientSecret!,
            confirmParams: PlatformPayConfirmParams.applePay(
              applePay: ApplePayParams(
                merchantCountryCode: 'AU',
                currencyCode: 'AUD',
                cartItems: [
                  ApplePayCartSummaryItem.immediate(
                      label: "Total Amount",
                      amount: '${StorageManager().finalAmount}')
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
          print('paymentIntentResult: $paymentIntentResult');
          print(
              'paymentIntentResult.status: ${response.customerOrderDTO?.toJson()}');
          // if (paymentIntentResult.status == PaymentIntentsStatus.Succeeded) {
          //   _navigateToNextScreen(
          //       orderTotalPrice, response.customerOrderDTO?.orderNumber);
          // }
          if (paymentIntentResult.status == PaymentIntentsStatus.Succeeded) {
            _navigateToNextScreen(
                orderTotalPrice, response.customerOrderDTO?.orderNumber);
          } else {
            throw Exception(
                'Payment failed with status: ${paymentIntentResult.status}');
          }
        } catch (err) {
          print('Error: $err');
          String errorMessage = 'Error during payment';
          if (err is StripeException) {
            errorMessage = err.error.localizedMessage!;
          }
          CommonMethods.showFailreToast(errorMessage);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error: $error');
      CommonMethods.showFailreToast('Something Went Wrong - $error');
    }
  }

this will first call my server api and get payment intent then using stripe applepay gateway it gives applepay form and perform payment
